# Error with tar command, cannot install xampp 1.8.1 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: xampp

I am trying to install xammpp on my Ubuntu 13.04. What I did was downloaded xampp from SourceForge, and then in the terminal I created /opt directory like this:

```
mkdir /opt
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz -C/opt
```

and this error shows up:

```
tar (child): xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: The `/opt` directory is already created by default so you should not have to create it. I can only assume that you were in your /home directory when you created the /opt directory and you are going to be in a world of hurt trying to get this done. Here is a good tutorial for doing what you want to do, following it slowly and read it carefully: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/05/want-lamp-linux-apache-mysql-in-ubuntu-13-04/ and another here: http://setupguides.blogspot.com/2013/04/install-lamp-in-ubuntu-1304.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Example your xampp files in Downloads directory.

```
cd Downloads

sudo -s

tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz -C /opt
```

After install xampp you will get permission denied error. Therefore to fix this, run the following code in terminal.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Run the following command in terminal to start lampp,

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to encourage 777 permissions.

Comment: Perhaps this could have been a comment instead of an answer. You have made too many assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

[to install XAMPP](http://namhuy.net/3130/install-xampp-1-8-3-php-5-5-11-centos-sever.html)

```
# wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.3/xampp-linux-1.8.3-4-installer.run
# chmod 755 xampp-linux*
# ./xampp-linux*
```